# Updating value of total customers without refreshing the page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, stripe-payments

I count my total customers in my view with `Stripe::Customer.all.count`. How can I get this number to dynamically update after the value changes, without refreshing the page?

Answer (score 0):

You do need to create a webhook in your stripe account which will fire when new customer account created in stripe. possibly it will call on `customer.created`.

You do need to action in you application which entertain this hook. And on this action you can use [sync](https://github.com/chrismccord/sync) gem to dynamically update count as @asad suggested.

[Here](http://www.gotealeaf.com/blog/stripe-recurring) You can find how to create a webhook in stripe and using [stripe api doc](https://stripe.com/docs/api/ruby#intro) You can find events which can be handle using webhook.

[This](https://github.com/integrallis/stripe_event) gem might also help you.

Comment: Wouldn't something like

`$(document).ready(function() {
       $("#MyDivId").load("YourScript.php");
       var refreshId = setInterval(function() {
          $("#MyDivId").load('YourScript.php');
       }, 5000);
       $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });
    });` Work with replacing the YourScript with Stripe::Customer.all.count?

Comment: No it will increase server load. Unnecessary query will fire. Sync will update only when record updated in stripe.